# running PS script with arguments

Tags: powershell, arguments, parameter-passing

I know how to run scripts with parameters like `script.ps1 -arcive=true`
but I'm trying to run my script with parameters like `script.ps1 -archive`.
is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a switch. Its the same concept as a parameter because it is a parameter.

```
 param (
    [string] $randomParameter,
    [switch] $archive = $false
 )
```

$archive will be false unless you call: `script.ps1 -archive`, then it will be true